# xpages get UNID for a document/datasource

Tags: xpages

I'm using [Mark Hughes picklist](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?name=View%20Picklist%20Custom%20Control) on my xpage which is using a datasource. The view from which I pick the values is listing documents having another datasource.

I put the selected value into an `<xp:inputText>`. I do want to create a link which should redirect me to the listed document from the view ( from it I took the value ). In other words, I do want to find out the UNID of the document from the view, which I did selected it.

I tried the following code for the ssjsSelectFunction:

```
var unid = viewScope.unid;

if(typeof unid != "undefined" && unid != null)
{
var doc = database.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
var val1 = doc.getItemValueString("txt_numeAcord_1");
var val2 = doc.getUniversalID();

getComponent("inputText24").setValue(val1);
getComponent("inputText25").setValue(val2);
}
```

But after selecting the desired doc. from the picklist, only `inputText25` is updated with the value ( UNID ), the `inputText24` is empty. Only if I open again the picklist and select the doc., the `inputText24` field value is added. I guess I'm missing something.

How can I achieve this?

My xpage code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" >
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="Contr" formName="(fmFormularCIP)"></xp:dominoDocument>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="vwAcord"></xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:panel id="AcordCadru">
        &#160;&#160;&#160;

        <xp:br></xp:br>
        &#160;&#160;
        <xp:checkBox text="Acord cadru" id="checkBox6"checkedValue="Da" uncheckedValue="Nu" value="#{Contr.chkAcord}">

            <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="AcordCadru">
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:checkBox>
        &#160;

        <xp:inputText id="inputText24" value="#{Contr.acord}">


        </xp:inputText>

        <xc:viewpicklist rowsPerPage="10"
            buttonImage="./folder_explore.png" tableClass="tablecellgreen"
            headerClass="headerclass" rowClass="odd, even" searchBar="false"
            searchButtonText="Search" searchButtonClass="button2"
            searchBarClass="headerclass" pagerStyleFirst="navbutton1"
            pagerStylePrevious="navbutton2" pagerStyleCurrent="navbutton4"
            pagerStyleNext="navbutton2" pagerStyleLast="navbutton3"
            typeAheadBar="false" select="UNID" onReturn="Set Scope Value"
            bottomBarClass="bottomround headerclass" cancelButtonText="Cancel"
            cancelButtonClass="button2 floatthisright" type="Single Value"
            finishButtonText="Finish" finishButtonClass="button2 floatthisright"
            multiSelectButtonAddImg="./add.png"
            multiSelectButtonRemoveImg="./delete.png"
            picklistButtonClass="button" openDialogWith="Button"
            picklistLinkImg="./add.png" multiSelectLinkAddImg="./add.png"
            multiSelectLinkRemoveImg="./delete.png" selectWith="Button"
            multiValueSeparator="," clearSearchImg="./cross.png"
            SelectCellWidth="30px" dialogID="dialog1"
            dialogTitle="Alegeti nr. acord cadru" fieldName="inputText24"
            refreshID="AcordCadru" datasrc="view1" selectColumn="0"
            varName="viewScope.unid">
            <xc:this.viewColumn>
                <xp:value>0</xp:value>




                <xp:value>1</xp:value>
                <xp:value>2</xp:value>
                <xp:value>3</xp:value>
                <xp:value>4</xp:value>
            </xc:this.viewColumn>

            <xc:this.ssjsSelectFunction><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var unid = viewScope.unid;

if(typeof unid != "undefined" && unid != null)
{

var doc = database.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
var val1 = doc.getItemValueString("txt_numeAcord_1");
var val2 = doc.getUniversalID();


Contr.setValue("acord",val1);
Contr.setValue("sv",val2);
}}]]></xc:this.ssjsSelectFunction>
        </xc:viewpicklist>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        &#160;&#160;&#160;

        <xp:inputText id="inputText25" value="#{Contr.sv}">


        </xp:inputText>
    </xp:panel>


</xp:view>
```

Comment: a) Does your document have a txt_nume_Acord_1 ? b) Don't go after components... set the value of the item the component is bound to. Always keep in mind: a component is part of the VIEW. You update the MODEL. If you update the view there is a risk that the model updates your VIEW and overwrites the changes you made

Comment: @stwissel a) Yes, there is a txt_numeAcord_1 ( and not a txt_nume_Acord_1 ). b) I also try: Contr.setValue("acord",val1); - where Contr is the datasource of the doc where the cc lays and acord is a field. Still the same result: after I select a doc. from picklist: the 2nd field is updated immediately with the UNID, but the 1st field isn't completed. I must reopen the picklist and reselect again the value as the 1st field to be updated with the txt_numeAcord_1 value.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example and paste the entire page. There must be a detail we overlook right now

Comment: @stwissel I added my code. Hope to get it work.

Comment: Florin, there are quite some dependencies in your code. So when I paste it into a XPage it doesn't run. The form is missing, the view is missing, the sample data is missing. Create a new empty database with a minimal working example and upload it somewhere.

Comment: In your code you have unid, but you query it again using doc.getUniversalId(); Check if that is the same **and** check if that unid is actually existing (print it out).

Comment: unid is just a variable. thanks for your help

Comment: Unid is the variable you use to retrieve the document. The first check would be: is unid the same a getUniversalid(). If not you found part of the problem

Comment: It is the same. The problem is, I think, at the refresh part. I do select a doc., the UNID is not added after closing the picklist, but only after I refresh again that panel which holds the respective field.

Comment: Provide a sample database with working problem - everything else will stay guesswork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputText24` doesn't get the selected value because the execution of `ssjsSelectFunction`'s code is too late. It gets executed during the refresh of panel "AcordCadru" caused by parameter refreshID. All fields positioned in front of `xc:viewpicklist` get refreshed *before* `ssjsSelectFunction`'s code execution. That's why `inputText24` doesn't get the new selected value but `inputText25` which comes after `xc:viewpicklist` does.

If you put `inputText24` behind `xc:viewpicklist` then it will get the new selected value.

But, probably you want to have field `inputText24` first and the picklist button `xc:viewpicklist` after. For this

- delete the `ssjsSelectFunction` code
- add a computed field in front of `inputText24` with pretty the same code

  ```xml
  <xp:text
      escape="true"
      id="computedField1">
      <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
          var unid = viewScope.unid;          
          if (unid && unid !== Contr.sv) {
              var doc = database.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
              var val1 = doc.getItemValueString("txt_numeAcord_1");
              Contr.setValue("acord",val1);
              Contr.setValue("sv",unid);
          }
          return "";
          }]]></xp:this.value>
  </xp:text>
  ```

  It will set the new selected values to document and made them visible in `inputText24` and `inputText25` right away.

Comment: You're right. That was the problem: inputText24 was before the xc:viewpicklist. I just put it behind the xc:viewpicklist, it works. I will test your code, also.